Azure Data Factory Copy Activity appends table in sink
I have a problem with a copy activity in Azure Data Factory.
The setup is the following.

The first copy data activity has Salesforce as a source. It receives one date from a query and writes the result in a Fabric Lakehouse table. The table action is set to "Overwrite," which means the table will never grow, and only one row will always be overwritten.
The second copy data action receives the same value from the table and sinks it in another Fabric Lakehouse table with the same settings as the first one. However, this one appends the table instead of overwriting it.
Here's the result of the sink table:

Does anyone know why the "overwrite" doesn't work here?

This seems to be a bug in Azure Data Factory.
When I create a new pipeline with just one "Copy data" activity and set everything up as I described (read from one table, write into another, and option "Overwrite"), this is what the resulting JSON looks like.
It adds "OverwriteSchema" instead of "Overwrite".
I changed it manually in the JSON, and now everything works as expected.

Now, I manually changed the "tableActionOption" to "Overwrite," and everything works as expected.


You can make your answer as accepted, which might benefit the community who are facing the similar issue.

First try the below steps and check if it works or not.

This might be due to cache issue as it might take some time to reflect the changes to the default settings. First publish the pipeline and close it. Re-open after some time and check if it gives the same result or not.

Instead of dynamic parameterized datasets, first check whether it works with their individual datasets or not.

Sometimes, it also might be the problem with UI. So, try to change the settings in the pipeline JSON. Go to Pipeline JSON ({}) on the top right and make sure the value is Overwrite and save the pipeline.



If it still results the same, as a temporary workaround, create a notebook in the fabric with truncate table query of your table and execute it before your copy activity using a web activity.
You can check this REST API to run the notebook from ADF web activity.
